# Proving equivalence of statements on continuity between metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

On page 228 of Mícheál Ó Searcóid's *Metric Spaces* (2007), he writes

> **Criteria for Comparability of Metrics**
>
> Suppose $X$ is a set and $d$ and $e$ are metrics on $X$. Then the following statements are equivalent:
>
> $\vdots$
>
> (iv) The identity function from $(X,d)$ to $(X,e)$ is continuous.
>
> $\vdots$
>
> (vi) Every function from $X$ into a metric space that is continuous with respect to $e$ is continuous with respect to $d$, the codomain being assumed to have its metric unaltered.
>
> (vii) Every function from a metric space into $X$ that is continuous with respect to $d$ is continuous with respect to $e$, the domain being assumed to have its metric unaltered.

In the proof, he writes

> It is a special case of either (vi) or (vii) that the identity function from $(X,d)$ to $(X,e)$ is continuous.

Can you substantiate this claim?

My thoughts are as follows:

Assume (vii) is true. Let $\text{id}^{-1}:(X,e)\to(X,d)$ be a continuous inverse identity map, then $\text{id}^{-1}:(X,e)\to(X,e)$ is continuous, which implies that $\text{id}:(X,e)\to(X,e)$ is continuous. Now, only if we assume that (vi) holds as well, then $\text{id}:(X,d)\to(X,e)$ is continuous. Similarly, if we start off assuming (vi) holds, then (vii) is required at the third implication to complete the assertion that $\text{id}^{-1}:(X,e)\to(X,d) \implies \text{id}:(X,d)\to(X,e)$.

So, to me, we need both (vi) and (vii) to get (iv).

Comment: If your question is how can (vi) (or (vii)) imply (iv), then the answer is most likely that the statements in (vi) and (vii) are for **every** function. Hence since $id: (X,e) \rightarrow (X,e)$ is continuous (by definition of $id$) we have that $id: (X,d) \rightarrow (X,e)$ is continuous. So also for the inverse of $id$, which is $id$ itself. This can done for each implication.

Comment: @TimHuijgens okay, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume (vii), and let $i:X\to X$ be the identity function. Clearly $i$ is continuous as a function from $\langle X,d\rangle$ to $\langle X,d\rangle$, so by the hypothesis (vii) it is continuous as a function from $\langle X,d\rangle$ to $\langle X,e\rangle$, and (iv) holds.

Now assume (vi). The function $i$ is continuous as a function from $\langle X,e\rangle$ to $\langle X,e\rangle$, so by the hypothesis (vi) it is continuous as a function from $\langle X,d\rangle$ to $\langle X,e\rangle$, and again (iv) holds.

Answer (score 1):

> (vi) Every function from $X$ into a metric space that is continuous with respect to $e$ ...

Take the function $\text{id}:(X,e)\to(X,e)$, $(X,e)$ being the arbitrary metric space. Then, by (vi), $\text{id}:(X,d)\to(X,e)$ is continuous.

Similarly with (vii), take $(X,d)$ as the arbitrary metric space.

My idea for this answer was thanks to [Tim Huijgens](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/215372/tim-huijgens) in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1796965/proving-equivalence-of-statements-on-continuity-between-metric-spaces#comment3669060_1796965).